# Why wrapped flexbox column aligned items with huge space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is one container with 4 squares.
Container use flexbox, with flex-direction set to column. Items can be wrapped, but has to start from the beginning of new column.
[image: why space between flexbox columns]
My question is:
Why there is a space between first and second column with items?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flexbox</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #995DB5;
    }
    
    #container {
      height: 300px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: flex-start;
      border: 5px solid white;
    }

    .child {
      width: 100px;
      height: 65px;
      margin: 10px;
      padding-top: 35px;
      background-color: #F7941F;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's because your `container` is full width and the children are only 100px. The rest space is added to the layout. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: If you remove flex-direction: column; it will default to row and then wrap based on screen size. If you're looking to create a grid have a look here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I see, so because width of the container is not defined and there are two columns so each column will take 50% of the layout. Space is the fallback of the column width. So if there would be 3 columns then, each of them will take 33% of layout space?